# Webex Bot framework how to show user selected button text

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, webex

I'm using MS Teams bot and Webex teams bot, I have some Adaptive-Card buttons on my bot message and I want to know which Adaptive Card button is pressed, by wrting it as a user message.
In MS Teams I can do that:

```
{
  "type": "Action.Submit",
  "title": "Click me for imBack",
  "data": {
    "msteams": {
        "type": "imBack",
        "value": "Text to reply in chat"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do it in webex? I cannot find any documentaion talking about it

Comment: Are you developing any Teams App?

Comment: I use a teams bot, and send messages to a user from my nodejs code. Now we want to add also webex

Comment: Nodejs with Webex Rest API

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Bot Builder Community [Webex Adapter](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/1d5a98b2781fa3cef0b4a605c1c841e48d6e4891/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Webex). There is also a [sample](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/ba7bf656bc1fe55b86f5ffe7e2b95af62e4041d8/samples/Webex%20Adapter%20Sample/README.md) that shows how to use it (C# linked).